# Can't view Metamask accounts via Solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to deploy my first smart contract using Solidity, infura, and the rinkeby test network.  Using my code below (I didn't down the actual 12 word seed below nor the actual infura address), I'm getting undefined for the accounts after console.logging them.  Are there any other troubleshooting steps that I can take to see why my accounts are not being returned?

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'some group of 12 words',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/tPr7mQGKgW8bLXuLZlHQ'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log(accounts)
};

deploy();
```

Comment: If you want your MetaMask accounts to show up, you need to use MetaMask as your web3 provider. The current code connects to Infura and asks _it_ for a list of accounts. (Infura is a public node, so it doesn't know anyone's account private keys.)

Comment: So, is there a MetaMask URL that I'm supposed to be pointing to?  (I thought that I was supposed to point to infura so that I wouldn't have to run my own node locally.  But, with the method above, I could still access my private wallet in MetaMask...)

Comment: To use MetaMask, you use `web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);`. (Be sure to do that after page load so MetaMask has had time to inject its `web3` instance already.)